# Trying to use a classification library on PHP with github

Tags: php, github

Specifically I want to use this
https://github.com/camspiers/statistical-classifier
and also I'm learning how github works at the same time basically.
What I have done:

- Cloned the library using github shell.
- Copy the sample code.
- Run the php through xampp
- File opens but it can't find the library.

Now my question is, where is the cloned library located at and how do I access it from the php file? the sample says

```html
use Camspiers\StatisticalClassifier\Classifier\ComplementNaiveBayes;
use Camspiers\StatisticalClassifier\DataSource\DataArray;
```

but when running it says class not found so there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: most PHP libraries use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). To learn more  [getting started with composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Answer (score 0):

Just by cloning the repository will not install the required libraries and as you are new to github,make it a note to read always the **README file** of the git repository, which will include all the instruction on how to use/run the code.

I can see in the README file of your cloned repository some installation steps https://github.com/camspiers/statistical-classifier#installation which talk about installation of some library and your code will depend on these libraries.

Please don't skip and step mentioned in the **README**  file and still if it doesn't work , then you can always get in touch with the committer of the GitHub code and get your queries resolved.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using windows with xampp. How do I install it here?

Comment: I just installed composer for windows, I'll see if I can install it now.

Comment: in Installation step there is a link where it talk about the installation on windows machine refer this link for more information https://github.com/ianbarber/php-svm

Comment: Nope, the library is not accessible for some reason. I'll try it later, if doesn't work then I guess I had to use Linux.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid Did I help you? Or you found another solution. Please share any result.